# Calling a method within other method definitions and 'object has no attribute'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

So I've been solving problems utilizing classes for the sake of practicing, but I've been having troubles with calling a method defined in a class, within a method definition of the same class

```
class Hive:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self._arr = arr
        self._index = ['Re','Pt','Cc','Ea','Tb','Cm','Ex']
        self._number = [0] * 7
        self._ratio = [] 
        self._len = len(self._arr)

    def number(self):
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(self._len):
                if self._index[i] == self._arr[j]:
                    self._number[i] += 1

        return self._number

    def rate(self):
        population = self._arr.number()
        for x in range(7):
            self._ratio.append(population[x] / self._len)

        return self._ratio

    def prnt(self):
        population2= self._arr.number()
        rate2 = self._arr.rate()
        for k in range(7):
            print("%s %d %.2f" % (self._index[k], population2[k], rate2[k]))
        print("Total", str(self._len), "1.00")

arr = input().split()
Colony = Hive(arr)
Colony.prnt()
```

This ends up with an error that states the following:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inee.py", line 33, in <module>
    Colony.prnt()
  File "inee.py", line 25, in prnt
    population2= self._arr.number()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'number'
```

So the only way I could remedy this with my current knowledge was to take care of list assignments outside the method definitions:

```
class Hive:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self._arr = arr
        self._index = ['Re','Pt','Cc','Ea','Tb','Cm','Ex']
        self._number = [0] * 7
        self._ratio = [] 
        self._len = len(self._arr)

    def number(self):
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(self._len):
                if self._index[i] == self._arr[j]:
                    self._number[i] += 1

        return self._number

    def rate(self, array):

        for x in range(7):
            self._ratio.append(array[x] / self._len)

        return self._ratio

    def prnt(self, array2, array3):

        for k in range(7):
            print("%s %d %.2f" % (self._index[k], array2[k], array3[k]))
        print("Total", str(self._len), "1.00")

arr = input().split()
initial = Hive(arr)
population = initial.number()
rateList = initial.rate(population)
initial.prnt(population, rateList)
```

This yielded results I wanted, but what's wrong with the first one? Is that not a correct way of calling methods within a method definition within a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By callint `prnt()`-method, you are referring to `self._arr`. This is not your `Hive`-object which has the `number()`-method. It's simply a list. A list does not have a `number()` attribute. The way you wrote your script you can only call `number()`-method on the `Hive`-object itself: `self.number()`, instead of `self._arr.number()`.

This counts for `rate()`-method and `prnt()`-method:

```
def rate(self):
    population = self.number()  # <-- here
    for x in range(7):
        self._ratio.append(population[x] / self._len)

    return self._ratio

def prnt(self):
    population2 = self.number()  # <-- here
    rate2 = self.rate()  # <-- and here
    for k in range(7):
        print("%s %d %.2f" % (self._index[k], population2[k], rate2[k]))
    print("Total", str(self._len), "1.00")
```

The second variant you provided cannot work, because you're using `number()`-method on `Hive`-object which has no longer a defined attribute `number()`, because you outsourced it. But you can use it now as a function like this:

```
>>> arr = ["This", "is", "a", "test", "Re", "Cc", "Tb"]
>>> initial = Hive(arr)
>>> population = number(initial)
>>> print(population)
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! The first variant really has been bugging me for a while.